# UINavigationItem RGB Swift

Tags: swift, rgb, uinavigationitem

I'm currently having difficulty setting the background color of a UINavigationItem. The following line of code is the only one that has worked so far:

```
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.barTintColor = UIColor(red: 0.55, green: 0.55, blue: 0.55, alpha: 1)
```

But the problem with this line is that the color of the bar is not the same as the rgb value should be. I have tried to change the translucency with the following line:

```
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.translucent = false
```

But this does not work either. I expected to get a dark gray color equivalent to the hex value #333333. But instead I received a lighter gray. Any help to remedy the problem is greatly appreciated!

Comment: We need more information about what you expect and what you get.

Comment: Thank you. I added more information to clarify that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To take full control of a navigation bar's color, do this:

- Set its `translucent` to `false` as you are doing
- Make (in code) a UIImage that is simply a rectangular swatch of the desired color, and set that as the navigation bar's `backgroundImage` (for whatever the relevant `metrics` is, usually `default`.

Now the navigation bar will be exactly the color you asked for.

Comment: Note, however, that your question is unclear, because the color of the navigation bar isn't really the same as the color of a UINavigationItem. The UINavigationItem contains UIBarButtonItems, and they have their _own_ backgrounds.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! I plan to try that this evening. I'm sorry for the confusion I was unsure of the difference between the UINavigationItem and bar itself because of a tutorial I was attempting. Thank you again for your help.

Comment: Thank you again. While using your solution I found the root cause of the problem.